# GitHub says authored and committed different people but it's the same person and same account

Tags: github

I am confused, GitHub shows me as two different people. I use the same account when pushing from my local repos and then checking it on GitHub.

I only have one account on GitHub. So it's a surprise to me I'd be shown as two different people.

[image]

Comment: That's probably because you don't have the same email address on your local git and github account. Check https://github.community/t5/Support-Protips/Why-is-my-commit-associated-with-the-wrong-person/ba-p/6728 and https://help.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user

Comment: @MickaelB. I indeed did not have an email address selected in my account on github. I chose an email now but it's still showing wrong. Moreover, my name in that commit does not point to my profile, but it should. It's like github wouldn't know who I am.

Comment: Well for this commit it's too late now since the information is already written, try to make a new commit or amend this one.

Comment: @MickaelB. If you want to post your answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It happens when you don't have the same email address on your local **git** configuration and on your **GitHub** account.

You can set your email address in **git** with this command:

```
git config --global user.email "email@example.com"
```

And on **GitHub** at this address: https://github.com/settings/emails

---

For more information, see **GitHub**'s help:

- [Why are my commits linked to the wrong user?](https://help.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user)
- [Why is my commit associated with the wrong person?](https://github.community/t5/Support-Protips/Why-is-my-commit-associated-with-the-wrong-person/ba-p/6728)

---

Note that the changes will take effect for next commits, the commit history won't be changed, if you want to change the author or committer on already existing commits, you'll have to [`amend`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) them.

Answer (score 3):

Also had the same issue. This strange behaviour apparently only happens to me when the locally configured git email has caps:

**Commits:**

```
$ git log --pretty=full

commit b1149b046e31a82de34d550dda53637908d1956b (HEAD -> feature1, 
origin/feature1)
Author: Sam <emailwithCaps@gmail.com>
Commit: Sam <emailwithCaps@gmail.com>

caps email

commit 0e1dcabfa7d3dc7f1333d2c15967ca6288515e42
Author: Sam <nonexistingemail@gmail.com>
Commit: Sam <nonexistingemail@gmail.com>

aasss2wq
```

As you can see, Author and Commiter have the same name and email on the commits.

On **GitHub**:
[Commit Email with caps vs no caps on GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msDpI.jpg)

Not sure why it happens.

**Concluing**: Making all characters **lower case** in the local git config **user.email** seemed to solve this for me.